# Show $\int_0^t (t-x)P_n(x)\,dx\leq \frac{t^2}{2}\int_0^1 P_n(x)\,\mathrm dx $ where $P_n(x)=(x(1-x))^{n}$

Tags: inequality, polynomials, integral-inequality

> Show that for all $t\in [0,1]$, and for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$,
>   $$\int_0^t (t-x)P_n(x)\,dx\leq \frac{t^2}{2}\int_0^1 P_n(x)\,dx\tag{*}$$
>   where $P_n(x)=(x(1-x))^{n}$.

Since $P_n\geq  0$ over $[0,1]$ then  $\int_0^y P_n(x)\,dx\leq \int_0^1 P_n(x)\,dx$ for any $y\in [0,1]$, and it follows easily that for all $t\in [0,1]$,
$$\int_0^t (t-x)P_n(x)\,dx=\int_0^t\int_0^y P_n(x)\,dx\,dy\leq t\int_0^1 P_n(x)\,dx.$$
On the other hand, 
$$\int_0^t (t-x)P_n(x)\,dx\leq\int_0^t (t-x)\,dx \cdot \max_{x\in[0,1]}P_n(x)=\frac{t^2}{2}\max_{x\in[0,1]}P_n(x),$$
but $\max_{x\in[0,1]}P_n(x)>\int_0^1 P_n(x)\,dx$ for $n>0$.

The inequality with $(*)$ seems to be much harder. Is it known? Any reference is welcome.

Comment: The integral $x$ ranges from $0$ to $t$ where $t\in[0,1]$. Then $0\leq x\leq 1$. We can make the substitution $x=\cos^2\theta$. Then $P_n(x)$ becomes $\cos^{2n}\theta\sin^{2n}\theta$. Would it help?

Comment: @ShubhrajitBhattacharya I tried but there was no improvement :-(

Comment: Where does the inequality come from? Why do you think that it is true? Did you try to verify it for small values of $n$?

Comment: If we make the substitution $\frac{x}{t}=u$, then we have, $$\int_{0}^{t}(t-x)P_n(x)dx = \int_{0}^{1}t^2(1-u)P_n(ut)du$$. Then the inequality becomes, $$\int_{0}^{1}(1-u)P_n(ut)\leq \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}P_n(x)dx$$

Comment: @MartinR I came across the case $n=2$ for a different thing and then I tried a generalization. Yes, I verified the inequality numerically for small values of $n$.

Comment: $$(x(1-x))^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}x^{k+n}$$
$$\int_{0}^{1}P_n(x)dx=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}x^{k+n}dx=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\int_{0}^{1}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}x^{k+n}dx=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\frac{1}{n+k+1}\binom{n}{k}$$

Similarly 
$$(ut(1-ut))^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(ut)^{k+n}$$
$$\int_{0}^{1}(1-u)P_n(ut)du=\int_{0}^{1}(1-u)\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(ut)^{k+n}du$$$$=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\int_{0}^{1}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}t^{k+n}(u^{n+k}-u^{n+k+1})du=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\frac{t^{n+k}}{(n+k+1)(n+k+2)}\binom{n}{k}$$

Comment: So the inequality can be written as,
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\left(\frac{1}{2(n+k+1)}-\frac{t^{n+k}}{(n+k+1)(n+k+2)}\right)\binom{n}{k}\geq0$$

Comment: I'm trying through different approaches, posted one of them. Maybe helpful, maybe not.

Comment: @ShubhrajitBhattacharya Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a proof using probabilistic arguments.

$$f_n(t):=\frac{1}{k} P_n(t) \ \ \text{with} \ \ k:=\int_0^1 P_n(t)dt,$$ when restricted to interval $[0,1]$, is the pdf of a classical probability law : $\beta(n+1,n+1)$ (beta distribution).

Remark (to be used further on) : the curve of $f_n$ being symmetrical with respect to vertical line $t=1/2$, the curve of its cdf $F_n$ is symmetrical with respect to point $P(1/2,1/2)$ (see figure showing different cdf for $n=2\cdots 10$).

Dividing LHS and RHS of the given inequality

$$t\int_0^t P_n(x)\,dx - \int_0^t xP_n(x)\,dx\leq \frac{t^2}{2}\int_0^1 P_n(x)\,dx\tag{*}$$

by the positive quantity $k$, it is equivalent to establish that

$$t\underbrace{\int_0^t f_n(x)dx}_{F_n(t)}-\int_0^t x f_n(x)dx \le t^2/2$$

$$\iff \ \ \forall t \in [0,1] : \ \ \underbrace{t^2/2 - tF_n(t) + \int_0^t xf_n(x)dx}_{\phi_n(t)} \geq 0 \tag{1}$$

Differentiating :

$$\phi_n'(t)=t-F_n(t)-\require{cancel} \cancel{tf_n(t)}+\cancel{tf_n(t)} \tag{2}$$

The curve of $y=t$ being symmetrical with respect to point $P(1/2,1/2)$, using the remark above, the curve of $\phi'$ will be symmetrical with respect to point $P$ ; therefore the curve of its primitive function will be symmetrical with respect to vertical line $t=1/2$.

Then, it is sufficient to establish property (1) for $0 \leq t \leq 1/2$. Here is how.

$F_n''(t)=f'_n(t)=kn(t(1-t))^{n-1}(1-2t)>0$ for $t \in (0,1/2)$ ; therefore, $F_n$ is convex in this domain ; consequently, as $F_n(0)=0$ and $F_n(1/2)=1/2$, the curve of $F_n$ is under the curve of $y=t$ for $t \in (0,1/2)$ ;

We can conclude, using (2), that $\phi_n'(t)>0$ in $(0,1/2)$. As $\phi_n(0)=0$ we can infer that (1) is true, always in this interval $(0,1/2)$. Consequently, as said above, it is valid for the whole interval $[0,1]$.

[image]

Comment: Following Jean Marie's solution, on the interval $(1/2,1)$ we have  $\phi_n(1)\leq\phi_n(t)$. Then $\phi(1)=\frac12-E[X]=0$  where $X$ is distributed as $\operatorname{Beta}(n+1,n+1)$. Thus, $\phi_n(t)\geq0$.

Comment: @Olover Diaz Thank you.  In fact, I just found a similar justification.

Comment: @JeanMarie Nice solution! Do you think that such inequality has some extension for other probability laws (other than beta distribution)?

Comment: @OliverDiaz Thanks for your comment. I wonder if such extension for some class of distributions has a reference in the literature.

Comment: @Robert Z: it seems that as long as the distribution $F$ with finite first moment  and such that $F(t)\leq g(t):=(1-E[X])\alpha t^{\alpha-1}$ on $(0,t^*)$  and $g(t)\leq F(t)$ otherwise ($(1-E[X])\alpha=1$),  Jean Marie's method would give you an inequality of the form 
$\int^t_0(t-x)F(dx)\leq (1-E[X])t^{\alpha}$

Comment: @Robert Z: S-shape distributions or maybe unimodal distributions (on [0,1] at least)

Comment: I have no special idea about a generalization. The only (poor) analogy I have seen is with Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistics based on the gap between two cdf (here $F_n$ and the cdf of the uniform density).

Answer (score 4):

Let
$$f(t) =  \frac{t^2}{2}\int_0^1 x^n(1-x)^n \mathrm{d} x - \int_0^t (t-x)x^n(1-x)^n \mathrm{d} x.$$
It is easy to prove that $f(t) = f(1-t)$ for all $t$ in $[0, 1]$ (the proof is given at the end).

Also, $f(0)=0$. Thus, it suffices to prove that $f(t) \ge 0$ for all $t$ in $(0, \frac{1}{2}]$.
We have
$$f'(t) = t\int_0^1 x^n(1-x)^n \mathrm{d} x - \int_0^t x^n(1-x)^n \mathrm{d} x.$$
Let
$$g(t) = \frac{\int_0^t x^n(1-x)^n \mathrm{d} x}{t}.$$
We have, for all $t$ in $(0, \frac{1}{2}]$,
\begin{align}
g'(t) &= \frac{t t^n(1-t)^n - \int_0^t x^n(1-x)^n \mathrm{d} x}{t^2}\\
&\ge \frac{t t^n(1-t)^n - \int_0^t t^n(1-t)^n \mathrm{d} x}{t^2}\\
&= 0
\end{align}
where we have used the fact that $x\mapsto x(1-x)$ is non-decreasing on $(0, \frac{1}{2}]$.
Thus, we have, for all $t$ in $(0, \frac{1}{2}]$,
\begin{align}
g(t) &\le g(\tfrac{1}{2})\\
& = 2\int_0^{1/2} x^n(1-x)^n \mathrm{d} x\\
&= \int_0^{1/2} x^n(1-x)^n \mathrm{d} x + \int_{1/2}^1 x^n(1-x)^n \mathrm{d} x\\
&= \int_0^1 x^n(1-x)^n \mathrm{d} x.
\end{align}
Thus, we have $f'(t) \ge 0$ for all $t$ in $(0, \frac{1}{2}]$. Thus, $f(t) \ge 0$ for all $t$ in $(0, \frac{1}{2}]$.
We are done.

$\phantom{2}$

*Proof of $f(t)=f(1-t)$*: Indeed, we have
\begin{align}
f(t) - f(1-t) &= \frac{t^2-(1-t)^2}{2}\int_0^1 x^n(1-x)^n \mathrm{d} x - \int_0^t (t-x)x^n(1-x)^n \mathrm{d} x\\
&\quad  + \int_0^{1-t} (1-t-x)x^n(1-x)^n \mathrm{d} x\\
&= \frac{2t-1}{2} \int_0^1 x^n(1-x)^n \mathrm{d} x - \int_0^t (t-x)x^n(1-x)^n \mathrm{d} x \\
&\quad + \int_t^1 (x-t)x^n(1-x)^n \mathrm{d} x \\
&= \frac{2t-1}{2} \int_0^1 x^n(1-x)^n \mathrm{d} x - \int_0^1 (t-x)x^n(1-x)^n \mathrm{d} x\\
&= -\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 x^n(1-x)^n \mathrm{d} x  + \int_0^1 xx^n(1-x)^n \mathrm{d} x\\
&= -\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 x^n(1-x)^n \mathrm{d} x\\
&\quad  + \frac{1}{2}
\left(\int_0^1 xx^n(1-x)^n \mathrm{d} x + \int_0^1 (1 - x)x^n(1-x)^n \mathrm{d} x\right)\\
&= 0.
\end{align}
We are done.